# What is missing if one icon from font awesome doesn't display

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-4

I selected a handful of icons to use, and they are all displaying except one. I compared my CSS with that of the icons page on the fontawesome site and I was missing some styles. I added the missing styles, but the icon still shows the placeholder instead of the icon.

HTML:

```
<i class="fa fa-pied-piper"></i>
```

CSS:

```
.fa-pied-piper-square:before,.fa-pied-piper:before {content: "\f1a7";}
```

Again, all the other icons (14 of them) are displaying correctly, just not this one.

(Font Awesome 4.0.3)

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: Just checking: do you use a custom subset of glyphs?

Comment: can you provide a link?

Comment: we need to see the rest of your code.  if its too much to paste here, create a fiddle.  Many times I solve my own problems just by creating a fiddle and discover the error before even posting the question.  does the problem exist over multiple browsers?

Comment: No errors in the console. No custom glyphs. It's an intranet site, so I won't be able to share a link. I'm not sure what other code would help illuminate any issues. If I run Firebug and change 'fa-pied-piper' to 'fa-home' or to 'fa-gear' or several others, those show up just fine. I'll try a fiddle to see if that indicates anything interesting. This does persist across browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using FontAwesome minified CSS? If so, you may need to omit the semicolon. I don't see semicolons listed in the minified CSS rules. Mine looks like this and works:

{content: "\f1a7"}

Comment: I can't imagine that omitting the semicolon (which is being used correctly) would matter. I'm interested to see OP's reply.

Comment: semi-colon is not required on the last rule of a css rule-set.  doesn't make a difference if it is used or not

Comment: I did try removing the semicolon which did not change anything. One interesting thing though; in Firefox the missing icon shows the placeholder as a square with 'f1a7' inside it. If I change the CSS in Firebug to something that doesn't exist (like fa-blahblah) the placeholder disappears.